# How to get a file's latest update timestamp from Github API?

Tags: api, github

I'm using the `github3.py` Python package. I'm trying to get a file's latest update timestamp from Github API.

So far I used the repo's `file_content` API (which uses Github's `contents` API ) to get the file's content and metadata, and it worked fine, until the file size grew over 1MB. At that point I got an error telling me that I can't use this API For large files, but I can still retrieve their data via the `blob` API.

The problem is the `blob` API does not return the file's `last update` timestamp which I need. I've also tried accessing it via the `directory_content` API, which holds the file's metadata (without the file's content), but there the `last update` was empty too.

I basically have the SHA of the file I want, in the correct version/branch. How do I use that to get it's `last update` timestamp, when I can't use the `contents` API?

Comment: Note that `Last-Modified` is a header and so it's expected that it won't be returned as part of `directory_content` - but I'd hoped to get it back on `blob` API. What workarounds can I have for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this endpoint to list the commit with the `path` parameter for the file's path: `path/to/filename.ext`. This will return a header with `last-modified` for the file.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository